# Salesforce - Talend Integration: API limits

Tags: governorlimits, talend

We have created a API only user in our org, and are using Talend job (auth through this user) to login every 5 min and checking for any new opportunity created. 
If yes, then that opportunity is updated by a flag.

Not too familiar with Talend. Is there a chance of hitting any API limits with this? The Talend job every 5 mins everyday!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with Talend, but if you are making one callout every 5 mins with it, you should be completely fine from an API limit standpoint, depending on the edition of Salesforce you are on and what other API callouts you are making in your org.

You should review the Salesforce Api limitations here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm

---

*edit*

I can't speak for your org specifically, but based on the documentation here is an example scenario. If you're on Enterprise edition with 100 Salesforce licenses, that gives you a total of 115,000 api calls per 24 hours. Since your Talend callouts would be, hypothetically, one callout every 5 minutes, then you would end up with 12 per minute, or 288 per 24 hours, ***well below*** the api limit. But again, this is just an example scenario as I do not know your org edition or what licenses you have in your org, so you will have to look at the chart and calculate the actual numbers for your org. I also don't know what other api callouts or requests are being made in your org, so those will also hit your api limits as well.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Sure thing, I'll update my answer. But part of the reason I didn't leave the numbers in the answer is because it all depends on the context of the User's Salesforce edition, which I don't know, so I left the link for himn so that he can look at it and determine if he will cross the api limits.

Comment: I have unlimited edition with 50 licenses.
Perhaps, we will have just this api call on the opportunity object using the API user.

Comment: If those 50 licenses are all regular Salesforce licenses, then you would have a total of 250,000 api callouts allowed per 24 hours. Again, this is well more than you would be consuming with the Talend call out that you have described. But again, you also have to look into what other callouts you are making. If you go to setup and environments/monitor->system overview, you can find your org's total api usage for the past 24 hours to an idea of how much you're currently already using per day.